# Lightbox retaining width of the previous image

Tags: wordpress, lightbox

I am using lightbox to display the large versions of multiple thumbnails on this [website](http://www.elementdevelopment.co.uk/nicole_robert/catalogue/).

So the best way to describe my problem is to follow this steps below.

1. Click the second image - notice it loads with a width of 100%
2. Close the image and click on the first image followed by clicking on the right arrow to display the second image.
3. Notice how the width of the previous image is retained making the second image (after clicking next) is very small.

I imagine its a css / js issue any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is a css problem probably caused by bootstrap,
if you are using bootstrap add this line in your lightbox.css.

```
.lb-image{ max-width: inherit; }
```

Cheers!